# Spring Boot RabbitMQ access refused for user

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I've got two Spring Boot based application, one is producer which obtain data from external services and sends it to Rabbit, the second one is consumer which gets data from Rabbit and process it.

I'm using my own created virtual host named "*events*". I have two queues:

- *xevents* ( binded to amq.topic exchange with routing key 'xevent' )
- *yevents* ( binded to amq.topic exchange with routing key 'yevent' )

User which I created (xyuser) has permission to both of them defined as below:

```
virtual-host: 'events', configure-regexp: '', write-regexp: '^(amq\.topic|xevents|yevents).*', read-regexp: '^(amq\.topic|xevents|yevents).*'
```

Topic permissions are set as below:

```
virtual-host: 'events', exchange: 'amq.topic', write-regexp: '^(xevent|yevent).*', read-regexp: '^(xevent|yevent).*'
```

Overall both applications works fine, but with current configuration during the startup of CONSUMER I'm getting few logs with the same error:

```
ERROR o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory - Shutdown Signal: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=403, reply-text=ACCESS_REFUSED - access to exchange 'amq.topic' in vhost 'events' refused for user 'xyuser', class-id=40, method-id=10)
```

After that I'm getting regular SpringBoot log:

```
Started ConsumerApplication in 20.991 seconds (JVM running for 21.932)
```

And everything seems to work okay.

I've tried to set all the permissions to
`'.*' '.*' '.*'`
and with this configuration I'm not getting any logs with ACCESS_REFUSED.

If I set write permissions to only exchange: `^(amq\.topic).*` I'm getting ACCESS_REFUSED to QUEUE on Consumer application.

If I set write permissions to only queue: `^(xevents|yevents).*` I don't have errors on consumer, but have errors on producer with ACCESS_REFUSED to EXCHANGE amq.topic.

I don't know why it's logging ACCESS_REFUSED with first configuration, and it does it only on Startup, after that everything is working fine, but I would like to avoid that. I thought that can be caused by RabbitListener which tries to get messages before all configuration beans are initialized but in this case even with `'.*'` permission errors would appear.

I would like to achieve that xyuser can:

- Send messages on vhost *events* on amq.topic.xevent.* and amq.topic.yevent.*
- Get messages on vhost *events* from queue xevents and yevents

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Try turning on DEBUG logging to see what activity is trying to access that exchange during startup.